# Memory usage increase crazily when Chrome devtool opened

Tags: google-chrome, memory

I'm using Chrome on MacOS 10.11, when I call out the devtool, I can see the memory usage increase crazily and could use up to 60G of memory though my computer has only 16G memory. It's so weird and I can't find any answer about it.

The memory usage will continue increase even when I close the tab that I opened the devtool in until I close the whole Google Chrome App.

It doesn't seem like a JavaScript because I can reproduce it on every website. Here is a screenshot of my memory usage:

[image: Here is a screenshot of my memory usage]

Answer (score 1):

I have had exactly this problem for a really long time. Just opening the dev tools caused the Chrome process memory consumption to start increasing... even after all windows were closed. The application would not exit cleanly: I always had to force-quit.

I finally seem to have fixed it, by searching for and removing almost everything with the words 'google' and 'chrome' in the name, from my ~/Library folder.